# How to install based on api in mdt?

Tags: mdt

We have an API server which has details based on serial number of laptop/desktop.

Is there any way to check the details of the machine serial number and gather details from API server based on this machine while running the MDT and select the task sequence based on that automatically and install that specific task sequence?

Can anyone please suggest the possibilities and steps to acheive this.

@Elliot, I saw the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/osd/understand/using-task-sequence-variables) you shared, there the powershell task has options to create a ts variable.

[image: powershell task in sccm]

But, in mdt, there are limited options as you see.

[image: powershell task in mdt]

Comment: Yes, you can have PowerShell do the checks and set a TS variable by interfacing with the TS subsystem: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/osd/understand/using-task-sequence-variables#bkmk_run-ps. Even though it is for SCCM, it works in MDT too

Comment: Can you check the details added above

Comment: If you import the module for task sequences in powershell, you can create a new TS variable inside of powershell via code. You don't have to do it inside of them MDT itself because powershell interfaces with the task sequence subsystem

Comment: Can you please share details about that

Comment: It is in the first link I sent. You have to use the `TSEnvironment` object in PS during a running TS. That will allow you to interface directly into MDT from PS and manipulate execution, e.g. set a TS variable.

Comment: I tried running a powershell script by keeping that in Deployment share\scripts folder and accessing that here but it is not executed. I just tested adding a firewall exception only for RDP but not working. Even I kept that as Operating System install, the "Configure1" in the above screen

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is by the above text. Do you need help executing a PS script? Are you having issues accessing the `TSEnvironment` object? If you are having script execution issues, please open a new question.

Comment: The options you provided may be working with sccm but they are not available with MDT. You can try in demo lab to confirm that

Comment: They are available in MDT. I have done this before, see this tutorial for details: http://www.potentengineer.com/using-powershell-to-set-osd-task-sequence-variables/