# How to control mdt task sequence from data in API server?

Tags: windows, mdt

We have an API server hosted containing device serial numbers and the other details related to business units and all.

Is it possible to get data from the API server during MDT deployment of OS on a device.
It should send the device serial number as API request and in return based on the result, it should pick the machine name, OS type or task sequence from the list and even assigning admin groups and all other configurations.

Please suggest how to setup this.

Comment: Check out the comment thread on this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1082443/how-to-install-based-on-api-in-mdt. it might get you to the right place :-)

Comment: Yes thanks for sharing, but the post author replied as not supporting for MDT, it is supporting only for SCCM

Comment: The post author has not investigated the possibility and has dismissed the potential solution. I have responded to their request with a tutorial that includes the correct PoC code for MDT. I don't use SCCM, I use only MDT. I have personally used the TSEnv class in MDT before with no SCCM support.