# How to keep cheks for task sequence as first step?

Tags: mdt

In mdt task sequence as first step (before OS install), with system macaddress/machine serial number can we do API call and check task seqnce to continue or stop based on its value retruned from API?

Able to call API as post configuration step after OS install but not before it

Comment: Please see the comments of these questions: https://serverfault.com/q/1083797/216286 and https://serverfault.com/q/1082443/216286. Your solution requires PowerShell coding as described here: http://www.potentengineer.com/using-powershell-to-set-osd-task-sequence-variables/

Comment: It is not working if I keep before OS installation. Only working after OS installation.

Comment: Someone is suggesting to keep the same script in winpe. can you suggest anyway on that also

Comment: I'll build a PoC lab and get some code for you. For WinPE, you will need to ensure that WMI and PowerShell is turned on as well as the appropriate network drivers are installed to allow connectivity to the RestAPI. (Has been a few years since I had to do this)